# Loading dart file from embedded server

Tags: dart

I have created an embedded webserver on a sam3x(with rtos).  Just for fun I thought it would be cool to see if I could get dart to run on it as well.  My question is how does dartium ask for the .dart file?

I thought it would work similar to a js file.  In my current implementation when I load a very basic index.html.  I saved the dart.js from the bleeding edge server to the sd card.  Debugging I can see the css, js, ico files being loaded but no dart file.  Any thoughts would be great thanks.

```html
<h1>Test_app</h1>

<p>Hello world from Dart!</p>

<div id="container">
  <p id="text"></p>
</div>

<script type="application/dart" src="test_app.dart"></script>
<script src="dart.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have wiredsharked the whole transaction and I do not see the browser issuing a GET for the test_app.dart.  What is the standard procedure for running the dart file?

Comment: I have debugged a couple of the dart examples(on the web) and it looks like a GET is issued for the dart files in those cases.  I noticed that my header version was off (1.0 vs 1.1). I changed this but it did not seem to matter.  What could my webserver be sending Dartium that would cause it to not issue GETs for dart files?  It is like those lines are not even in the html file and I have verified that the html file has been transmitted in full.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure Dartium isn't caching any of the data from your server?  What kind expire headers is the server sending up for the .dart files?

Comment: Currently the server sends the 200 OK and content type then the file.  All of the files that are needed(html, css, dart.js, even favicon is loaded(sent) but not the dart file.) I can even click on view source and download the dart file manually. All of this is happening on a closed local network would that have any bearing(dart.js is saved on the same sd card as the website).

Comment: Can you throw some alerts into dart.js to see if it's executing (regardless of caching)? Then, add a bunch of alerts() to see what the code is doing.

Comment: I have added the webkitStartDart javascript code to the html page and that seems to have enabled the dart vm and I have been able to run a basic app.

Comment: To maintain history, this was also discussed, including the solution, on the [Dart google group](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/misc/Y7csvl9lL4E).

Comment: @Seth Can you please answer your own question so that other users or google searches can get to the solution easier? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the "navigator.webkitStartDart" js code on the dart site.  That worked and I was able to get the dart scripts to load and run so I am enthused about that.